# How can I rename all the indexes in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database where the names of indexes are shared between tables. Which is fine in MySQL, because index names only have to be unique within a table, and not within a database. But I have to export this database to a system that requires index name be globally unique.

Is there some command or script I can run to assign unique names to the indexes? I don't care if they are randomly generated.

Comment: There is no, but you can write custom script for that. A note: there is no way to rename index in mysql (prior to 5.7: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html), only drop+create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL supports no syntax in `ALTER TABLE` to rename an index (or key, which is a synonym).

You can `ALTER TABLE DROP KEY` and `ALTER TABLE ADD KEY`.

There is no `ALTER INDEX` command in `MySQL`. You can only [`DROP INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-index.html) and then [`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html) with the new name.

Answer (score 2):

As of the latest version of MySQL, there is no way to rename indexes. Your only option would be to `DROP` the index then `CREATE` a new one or just `CREATE` a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's worth highlighting what @zerkms alluded to in a comment above - you *can* rename an index (since [MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html)):

```
alter table mytable RENAME INDEX old_index_name TO new_index_name
```

Comment: When I try this in mySQL 5.7.17 I am seeing a Syntax error unexpected INDEX_SYM

Answer (score 1):

There is no `RENAME` or `ALTER` index command on MySQL.
You need to either `DROP` the index or `CREATE` a new one.